# iOS: reliable way to send push notification but let app decide if it has to be shown to the user?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to send push notifications from my server to the app, but the app has to decide if the push should be shown to the user or not. I tried with silent pushes first, but it seems as if they get throttled if there are sent multiple pushes in a short time.

Another option would be to send regular, high priority push and sometimes suppress them on the device, but I didn't find a way to achieve that.

Is there any (really!) reliable way to achieve this?

Comment: Whatsapp seems to do it if you mute a group chat — you can see the badge appear momentarily on the app icon.

Comment: I guess they are using Voip-Push, which will not be allowed for my (medical) app, I'm afraid...